# RecyclerView get height of first visible item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

How can i calculate the height of the first visible item in my `recyclerview` ?

```
  public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        switch (newState) {
            case RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
                Log.d("scroll_stop","The RecyclerView is not scrolling : ");
                View firstItemView = mGLM.findViewByPosition(mGLM.findFirstVisibleItemPosition());

                View mVizibleView= mPlm.findViewByPosition(mGLM.findFirstVisibleItemPosition());
}
  });
```

But this give me the full height of the view

Comment: Iirc Views get a size from Android at run-time, so my suggestion is to use separate XML files for each type of row, so you can use those sizes to calculate the actual pixels for the screensize of the device your app is on.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the Size of any RecyclerView Item is pointless, If you `getHeight()` or `getWidth()` of any item it's just gonna give a Null Error and your app is gonna crash.

What you can do, Is to Use your ViewHolder from recyclerView Adapter and First set a Specific Height to any Item you want and Then use that Height somewhere Else.

Look at the Code Below, Maybe helps:

```js
class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    RemaltiveLayout itemLayout;

    public myViewHolder(View itemView) {
      super(itemView);

      itemLayout = (RemaltiveLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.myItemLayout);


      itemLayout.getLayoutParams().height = res.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.height_value);
    }
```

You should be able to use item at a specific location position as well

This is not gonna work with Width though, cause items are always being stretched to fill columns of layoutManager

Answer (score 0):

Steps to get first item height:

1. Get the layout manager from the recyclerview reference in `onScrolled()`
2. Get the first the visible item position using `layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()`
3. If fist visible item position is 0 then get the 0th child height `layoutManager.getChildAt(0)`

Sample code:

```
RecyclerView.OnScrollListener scrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();

        if (layoutManager != null) {
            int child0Height = 0;
            int currentFirstVisibleItem = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            if (currentFirstVisibleItem == 0) {
                final View childAt0 = layoutManager.getChildAt(0);
                if (childAt0 != null) {
                    child0Height = childAt0.getHeight();
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```